Mileti-Godel's incompleteness theorem
I'm currently working through the exercises in Mileti's logic book, and have come across the following question. It aims to prove an extension of the first incompleteness theorem, specifically to show that for any that is, for any Σ ⊆ Th(N ) where ♯Σ is definable, we have Cn(Σ) ̸= Th(N ). The hint suggests for us to show that #Cn(Σ) is definable. Specifically, I'm confused as how we can show that ♯Σ is definable implies that #Cn(Σ)  is definable, where #Cn(Σ) is the set of godel numbers of every sentence of  Cn(Σ) , the theory  Cn(Σ) is the set
{τ ∈ SentL : Σ ⊨ τ}.

You should probably explain the notation so that people that don’t have the book in front of them can understand the question. You should probably also reference where the exercise is in the book so that people who do have the book in front of them can understand the question.

If $\Sigma$ is definable, then there is a definable provability predicate for $\Sigma$.
